# the value of a pointer passed in a function doesn't change in the main procedure

Tags: c, function, pointers

The value pointed by p does change inside the function but in the main procedure, it pintts out the previous value. How can I fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void changer(char *p, char user1[], char user2[]);
int main()
{
    char *p=malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char user1[10]="rania";
    char user2[10]="souad";
    p=user1;
    changer(p,user1,user2);
    printf("%s\n",p);
      return 0;
}
void changer(char *p, char user1[], char user2[])
    {
        if (p==user1){
           p=user2;
           }

        else
            p=user1;
    }
```

Comment: You need to research about "Pass by value vs Pass by reference in C". You only change a copy of your pointer

Comment: Apart from this being a common FAQ, you can't do stuff like `p=user1;`, that doesn't copy any data. You need to study how pointers work before anything else.